# Requirejs Optimizes multiple projects or pages

Tags: jquery, node.js, requirejs, rjs, requirejs-optimizer

How can I optimize my multiple requirejs projects? For instance I have this structure below where I have **two** `main.js` in different locations/ folders,

```
build/
   build.js

dev/    
   index.php
    core/
      js/
       main.js
       libs/
          jquery.js


    local/
      js/
        main.js
```

My build/build.js

```
({
    // Where my HTML and JS is stored.
    appDir: "../dev/",

    // Top-level directory containing my JS:
    baseUrl: "local/view/javascript/base/",

    // Where to build the optimized project.
    dir: "../dist",

    // Define the modules to compile.
    modules: [
        {
            name: 'main',

            mainConfigFile: '../dev/local/js/main.js'
        },
        {

            name: 'main',

            mainConfigFile: '../dev/core/js/main.js'
        }
    ]
})
```

It keeps failing compressing or finding the dependencies, such as,

> ERROR: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   'c:\wamp\websitename\dist\local\js\jquery.js

My `query.js` is located in `core/js/libs/` - whey is it looking for it in `local\js`?

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` appears twice in your `modules` setting. So you are telling `r.js` "please create the module `main` in `../dist` with such and such options and also create module `main` in `../dist` different options". How is `r.js` supposed to create two *different* modules that should be the *same* file in `../dist`? It can't.

You also cannot put `mainConfigFile` inside of a module configuration just like you do. It is a top level option so if you want to have a per-module setting you need to use `override`. And setting the `mainConfigFile` does not tell `r.js` what module you are in fact trying to optimize.

Something like this seems to be what is needed on the basis of what you describe in the question:

```
({
    // Where my HTML and JS is stored.
    appDir: "../dev/",

    // Top-level directory containing my JS:
    baseUrl: "local/view/javascript/base/",

    // Where to build the optimized project.
    dir: "../dist",

    // Define the modules to compile.
    modules: [
        {
            // Give a unique name.
            name: 'main_local',

            // This module does not exist in the source so tell r.js to 
            // *create* it.
            create: true,

            // What we want in it.
            include: ['../dev/local/js/main.js'],

            // "Override" the top level mainConfigFile, just for this module.
            override: {
                mainConfigFile: '../dev/local/js/main.js'
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'main_core',
            create: true,
            include: ['../dev/core/js/main.js'],

            override: {
                mainConfigFile: '../dev/core/js/main.js'
            }
        },
    ]
})
```

Comment: I still get the same error though... `ERROR: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'c:\wamp\websitename\dist\local\js\jquery.js`. I notice that it happens when `mainConfigFile: '../dev/local/js/main.js'` is moved inside `modules: []`...

Comment: I'm not sure why you mean by "moved inside `modules: []`. In your question it was *directly* inside `modules`. In my answer it is inside `override`, which makes `mainConfigFile` *indirectly* inside `modules`. Are you talking about a trial you made where you put `mainConfigFile` at the top level?

Comment: sorry, it was me put it in there first. it works ok now after moving it outside.